# Inject service into MVC Action Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

I'm developing a generic controller to handle File Upload and Download. My domain contains a general entity that will hold any file, and other child entities that will reference this one to hold the specific files reference.

I have a service for the general entity and lots of services for child specific entities.

Heres my scratch:

```
public class FileController : BaseController
{
  public JsonResult GetAll(IService childService) { /*lot of code*/}
  public FileResult Download(int id, IService  childService) { /*lot of code*/}
  public JsonResult Post(IService childService) { /*lot of code*/}
  public JsonResult Delete(IService childService) { /*lot of code*/}
}
```

**How can I inject the specific service into the action?**

If I don't do this way, I will get lot of junkie code doing the same stuff everywhere. Is there another way? Maybe a pattern that I did't realize?

Comment: You don't inject services into action methods. You inject them into the constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than inject into the action, inject the service into the class:

```
public class FileController : BaseController
{
    private IService _childService;

    public IService ChildService { set { _childService = value; } }

    public JsonResult GetAll() { /*lot of code*/}
    public FileResult Download(int id) { /*lot of code*/}
    public JsonResult Post() { /*lot of code*/}
    public JsonResult Delete(IService childService) { /*lot of code*/}
}
```

Then, create a custom `ControllerFactory` to extend `DefaultControllerFactory` and specify that in your `Global.asax` file.

Finally, have your custom `ControllerFactory` class override the `CreateController` method and inject the IService instance when creating the controllers.

Comment: Sounds good, but how I will notify the controller Factory to inject the specific service based on my request?

Comment: @Fals Updated to address that.